# What is the semantic type and the lexical entry for 'to be right'?

Tags: syntax, semantics, type-theory

Does somebody know what the lexical entry for '**(be) right**' is? And the semantic type of 'right' when its in the syntax tree.
Is it an attitude predicate?
For example in the sentence 'Beth is **right** that Ann won'

(Semantic type in the style of, e.g. 'student' being type <e,t> and the lexical entry like [λx ∈ De x .is a student] etc. maybe that makes my question easier :))

Everything in compositional semantics

Thank youuu :)